# get a dictionnary from a list with only 1 loop and no package import

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = ['A','5','-0.5','D','0.5','-3','A','8','-0.7','C','4','1.6','D','1','0.6']
```

From this list I want to get a dictionary with letters as keys and lists of tuples of floats as values, so that should be as follows:

```
d = { "A" : [(5 ,-0.5), (8 ,-0.7)] , "D" : [(0.5 ,-3) , (1 , 0.6)] , "C" : [(4 , 1.6)] }
```

As you can see, the keys are letters and the values are tuples, which contain the next two elements. In the given list, they are `str`, but they must be `float` in `d`.

IMPORTANT: Only one loop is allowed and must be performed **without** importing any package.

Comment: Try to show some effort of solving the problem on you own before asking other for the solution.

Comment: You say "must be `float`" but your desired output example shows some as ints. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
list1 = ['A','5','-0.5','D','0.5','-3','A','8','-0.7','C','4','1.6','D','1','0.6']
d={}
for x in range(0,len(list1),3):
  if list1[x] in d :
    d[list1[x]].append((float(list1[x+1]),float(list1[x+2])))
  else:
    d[list1[x]]=[(float(list1[x+1]),float(list1[x+2]))]
```

d is your new dictionary.

Comment: @aflatoon Sure! The `for` statement basically iterates through every 3rd object after the third. This means it only picks up the letters. Then, for each letter, it counts one and two after, and appends the numbers to the keys (the letters) in the dictionary. If the key doesn't exist, it creates one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use defaultdict for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
list1 = ['A','5','-0.5','D','0.5','-3','A','8','-0.7','C','4','1.6','D','1','0.6']
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0, len(list1), 3):
    d[list1[i]].append((float(list1[i + 1]), float(list1[i + 2])))
d
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'A': [(5.0, -0.5), (8.0, -0.7)],
             'D': [(0.5, -3.0), (1.0, 0.6)],
             'C': [(4.0, 1.6)]})
```

If you don't want to use import library, you can add another condition:

```
list1 = ['A','5','-0.5','D','0.5','-3','A','8','-0.7','C','4','1.6','D','1','0.6']
d = {}
for i in range(0, len(list1), 3):
    if list1[i] not in d:
        d[list1[i]] = []
    d[list1[i]].append((float(list1[i + 1]), float(list1[i + 2])))
d
```

Output

```
{'A': [(5.0, -0.5), (8.0, -0.7)],
 'D': [(0.5, -3.0), (1.0, 0.6)],
 'C': [(4.0, 1.6)]}
```

Edit: Add function to convert string to float

Comment: Indicated no imports… additionally indicated that the values must be float and not strings. Maybe you’re leaving that to be solved by the OP… but thought I would point it out… just in case it was missed.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, it has to be done without package import.

Comment: I added another solution without any import @aflatoon

Answer (score 2):

Having fun with iterators:

```
it = iter(list1)
nums = zip(*[map(eval, it)]*2)
d = {}
for c in it:
    d.setdefault(c, []).append(next(nums))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/LasMwELzrK/bm3aCYqs7DBHIoyV8YH4ylUIGjCFsJaUO@3V1JrmC0o5ndYeV/wvfNVbUf53mwU1BwhKb4KmSxZaw/yljOjMzWFV/RrbO753JibBiq3C29KvXvilaYpzd94MwX8BgcoMEtyBhLErBOdE8tSODBZLPFakUsoeKLc7J/yv6GuUraWwgbo20wI6bdSbj7dWLp13pcNdfOo3l0g@QWalefJHTc5C0utxF6sI71gwA@upxM0ObS3YeAvYSmpbLz3jiNzjwDxlgiIfxoXUBNC8m/@39x@BEWaZ7/AA)

Using `eval` because your desired output shows some numbers as ints despite your "must be `float`" request. Use `float` instead if floats are ok instead of ints.